# How to compare two DateTime strings and return difference in hours? (bash shell)

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I can do that in php with the following code:

```php
$dt1 = '2011-11-11 11:11:11';
$t1 = strtotime($dt1);

$dt2 = date('Y-m-d H:00:00');
$t2 = strtotime($dt2);

$tDiff = $t2 - $t1;

$hDiff = round($tDiff/3600);
```

`$hDiff` will give me the result in hours.

How do I implement the above in bash shell?

Comment: This is pretty hard to do in most shell environments.  I'd stick to a php script if that's what you're already comfortable with.  Perl and Python are also good at this sort of thing.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could use `date` command to achieve this. `man date` will provide you with more details. A bash script could be something on these lines (seems to work fine on Ubuntu 10.04 bash 4.1.5):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                   

# Date 1
dt1="2011-11-11 11:11:11"
# Compute the seconds since epoch for date 1
t1=$(date --date="$dt1" +%s)

# Date 2 : Current date
dt2=$(date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S)
# Compute the seconds since epoch for date 2
t2=$(date --date="$dt2" +%s)

# Compute the difference in dates in seconds
let "tDiff=$t2-$t1"
# Compute the approximate hour difference
let "hDiff=$tDiff/3600"

echo "Approx hour diff b/w $dt1 & $dt2 = $hDiff"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Found this probably about the same time you posted: http://www.unix.com/tips-tutorials/31944-simple-date-time-calulation-bash.html

Comment: for who may confuse, there' s no such command called "let". Define a variable instead.

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/let @tugcem no its you that is confused...