# compare file's date bash

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I'm working on a tiny dropbox-like bash script, how can I compare the dates of 2 files and replace the old one(s) with the new one without using **rsync**
is there any simple way to process this?
can the **SHA1** help me with knowing the newer?

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by the "date of a file".  You are probably referring to `mtime`, but specificity is good.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, the last modify i mean

Comment: For the record, the SHA1 absolutely does not reveal anything about the file's age, or name, or contents.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can compare file modification times with `test`, using `-nt` (newer than) and `-ot` (older than) operators:

```
if [ "$file1" -ot "$file2" ]; then
    cp -f "$file2" "$file1"
fi
```

Comment: that's awesome :))) never thought the simple compare could do the job since i'm new to centOS :)
thank u :)

Comment: -nt seems to mean newer than or same age.

Comment: @JoeC I tested and if same age returned 1 (after `touch -r ...`)

Comment: "$file1" not present implies true / cp ... ?

Comment: If the files are the same, -ot and -nt return false (1).  An absent file is treated as older than a present file.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a POSIX solution:

```
find -name file2 -newer file1
```

Answer (score 6):

Or even shorter and nicer, look at `man stat`:

```
stat -c %y file
```

Comment: Use %Y for seconds since epoch, much easier to use.

Comment: This is not portable, though. POSIX `stat` has a rather depressingly narrow set of options.

Comment: For anyone else running into this problem: If `FILE` is a symlink to another file, then `stat -c %Y FILE` will output the last-modified-date of the *symlink*, not the file the link is pointing at. Use `stat -L -c %Y FILE` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
stat file|awk -F': ' '/Modify: /{print $2}'
```

Comment: This one helped me out with what I was trying to accomplish.  Now, how to compare those times?  I'm using the answers found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116503/how-to-compare-two-datetime-strings-and-return-difference-in-hours-bash-shell  Perfect!