# Bash - How to compare two files last modified date, when they are remote?

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802807/compare-files-date-bash) one. Except the file I want to check the date of is on a remote server that I ssh onto/scp off of.
Basically I want to be able to compare the date a file was last modified on both my local machine and a remote server, and whichever one is newer copy to the other computer. I know how to do all the copying and stuff I just want to figure out how to compare the dates.

Comment: ["What is the XY problem?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Take a look at `man rsync`.

Comment: @cyrus I looked at rsync briefly but I want to be able to do this bi-directionally. I looked at the osync project but it seemed like it was overkill, so I thought id just program my own. The only problem I'm running into is knowing which file is most recent over ssh

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I know my X problem, I just need to tackle this date part for my solution to work. It's more education than function I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
remote=$(ssh user@server "stat -c %Y /path/to/remote_file")
[[ -z "$remote" ]] && exit 1 # stop on error ($remote is empty)
local=$(stat -c %Y /path/to/local_file)

if [[ $remote -gt $local ]]; then
  echo remote file is newer
else
  echo local file is newer
fi
```

Comment: Good deal. I might use `printf %q` to escape the path to the remote file so we don't convert tricksy filenames like `/tmp/$(rm -rf /)/hello` to commands, but this is pretty much spot on.

Comment: ...example: `printf -v quoted_filename %q "$filename"; ssh user@server "stat -c %Y $quoted_filename"`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thank you for this useful hint!

Comment: oh hey this makes a lot of sense, I'll use this I bet

Comment: For anyone else running into this problem: If `FILE` is a symlink to another file, then `stat -c %Y FILE` will output the last-modified-date of the *symlink*, not the file the link is pointing at. Use `stat -L -c %Y FILE` in this case.