# Remove docker containers those are running more than 8hrs

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, devops

Is there any way to remove the docker containers that are running|created for more than 8hrs?

Comment: An obvious solution is to run a cron job that runs every few minutes and brutally murders them if they go over 8 hours, but I'm assuming you want something cleaner.

Comment: Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71809040/how-to-filter-docker-containers-by-running-time). It´s a nice and simple script.